# Why does the support function equal the distance between $0$ and the supporting hyperplane?

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems, convex-geometry, support-function

I am currently revising the material in Luenberger's classic "optimization by Vector Space Methods" for an upcoming oral exam, and find myself stuck in section 5.13.

I am stuck on the following notion: let $K$ be a convex set in a real normed vector space, $X$. The support functional of a convex set $K \subset X$ is
$$h(x^*) = \sup_{x\in K} \langle x, x^*\rangle$$
where $x^* \in X^*$, an element of the dual of $X$.

I am confused about two properties of the hyperplane $\{x: \langle x ,x^* \rangle =h(x^*)\}$ (1., 2. below)

1. Luenberger claims, on page 136, that if $K$ does not contain $0$, then $h(x)$ may be regarded as the distance between $0$ to the hyperplane $\{x: \langle x ,x^* \rangle =h(x^*)\}$ for any $x^*$ with dual norm $1$. Here $h$ is the support functional of the convex set $K$, as defined above. I do not see why this is the case.
2. Moreover, there is a theorem on minimum norm duality just following this discussion, in the proof of which it is claimed that $h(x^*) = \inf_{x \in B(0,\epsilon^*)} \langle x, x^*\rangle$ where $\epsilon^*$ is the supremum over all radii such that the ball of radius $r$ around the origin is seperated from $K$ by the hyperplane $\{x: \langle x ,x^* \rangle =h(x^*)\}$. This looks very similar to 1. above but I don't see it...

I believe these claims to be closely related  but I cannot really get my head around either of them. I think part of my issue is that Luenberger is using mostly geometric language in his proofs, which I am not entirely comfortable with, without the supporting algebraic characterization. Any clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It was actually just an "easy" relaxation trick once I figured out how to write out Luenberger's statements more analytically. Set

$$h(x^*) = \sup_{x\in K} \langle x,x^*\rangle$$

and letting $\epsilon^* = \sup \{r : h(x^*) \leq \langle x,x^* \rangle, \forall x\in B(0,r)\}$, it is clear that $h(x^*) = \inf_{x\in B(0,\epsilon^*)} \langle x,x^*\rangle$ simply by optimizing over all upper bounds on $h(x^*)$...

This explains 2. and 1. is essentially now a consequence of the proof (of Theorem 1, section 5.13) (which I now think I understand).